# Start scrolling from center of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which has buttons on it, I have some jquery code that when the up or down buttons are pressed the next/previous button is focused. Is there a way to scroll from center, instead of top and bottom? I have setup and example [here](https://jsbin.com/rujagohona/edit?html,css,js,output) click on a button then keep pressing down, can it start scrolling only at center of div, instead of when it reaches the top or bottom?

```
let el=$('button');
for(var i = 1; i<=el.length; i++){
  el.eq(i-1).attr('tabindex',i);
}   


$('button').on('keydown', function(event) {
let currentTabIndex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
  let el = $('button');

var callback  = function(currentTabIndex){
  $('li').removeClass('selected');
  $("[tabindex=" + currentTabIndex + "]").focus();
  $("[tabindex=" + currentTabIndex + "]").parent().addClass('selected');

}
//Focus on categories if at top and up is pressed

  switch (event.which) {
    case 38:
      currentTabIndex = parseInt(currentTabIndex) - 1;
      if (currentTabIndex == 0) {
         callback(el.length)
      } else {
         callback(currentTabIndex)
      }
      break;

    case 40:
      currentTabIndex = parseInt(currentTabIndex) + 1;
      if (currentTabIndex == el.length+1) {
         callback(1)
      } else {

        callback(currentTabIndex)

      }
      break;
  }

});
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you mean. No scrolling is happening when buttons are clicked.

Comment: I want to make page scrolling only happen when you reach the center of the scrollable div. Currently scrolling happens when you hit the bottom/top of the overflow content, can I change that so it starts when you hit the center?